# ASP.NET buttonclick called after master page load when trying to create session

Tags: asp.net, session

I am trying to create a session when a user clicks a button.  I want to update controls on the master.aspx page after the session is created from the login button being clicked.  However the master.aspx page_load is being called before the button click function.  Any ideas on how I could work around this?

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void ButtonLoginIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["username"] = "Joe";
}
```

Master.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["username"] == null)
    {
        LinkLoginInOut.Text = "Sign In";
    }
    else
    {
        string sessionId = Session["username"].ToString();
        LabelDbUserName.Text = "Joe";
        LinkLoginInOut.Text = "Log Out";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `FindControl` on the `Master`

```
LinkButton lb = Master.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;
lb.Text = "LinkButton Master";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move the code in the Page_Load event of the masterpage to an event, that is called after the button_click event. That way the changes to the session occur before the updating of the masterpage. You can try the Page_LoadComplete event. Please check the "asp.net page life cycle" documentation for the sequence, in which the different page events are called.